# Use grep to extract some text from file based on regex

Tags: grep

I have this file:

```
header:
  title: hello
  version: 1.2.3
```

I want to extract the version number.

My original attempt was

```
grep ^\s+version:\s+(\d\.\d\.\d) file.txt
```

but that produced empty output. After suggestions in the comments, I tried

```
grep -P '^\s+version:\s+(\d\.\d\.\d)' file.txt
```

but I get "  version: 1.2.3" instead of "1.2.3".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `grep` uses a very basic regex by default, your regex works with `grep -P` (at least when quoted...).

Comment: Also, don't forget to quote your regex.

Comment: works but doesn't give me the group, but the whole line

Comment: That is normal behavior, you want `\K` or `(?<=...)`

Comment: I edited the question, could you please provide me an example saving that value inside of a variable as well?

Comment: Standard `sed`: `sed -n 's/.*version: //p' file`

Comment: In awk: `awk '/version/ { print $2 }' yourfile.txt`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`grep` uses [Posix Basic Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) (`BRE`) by default which does not support your notation.

Use `grep -E` to use Posix Extended Regex (`ERE`) and `grep -P` to use Perl Compatible Regex  (`PCRE`) if available.

Your notation works with `grep -P`:

```
grep -P '^\s+version:\s+(\d\.\d\.\d)' file.txt
```

This works with `BRE`:

```
grep '^ \+version: \+\([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\)' file.txt
```

Output:

```
  version: 1.2.3
```

Note, that the capture group is not necessary here, as `grep` doesn't do anything with it.

---

If you want the version nr only., [use `\K`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) and `-o` option:

```
grep -Po '^\s+version:\s+\K\d\.\d\.\d' file.txt
```

Output:

```
1.2.3
```

With `BRE`, this is not possible, you will need to chain two `grep` commands:

```
grep 'version: ' file.txt | grep -o '[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]'
```

or use `sed` (credits @Kusalananda):

```
sed -n 's/.*version: //p' file.txt
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use a capture group in your first two commands? The group isn't actually used anywhere as far as I can see.

Comment: That is just taken from the Q, I added a note that it's not necessary

Answer (score 3):

According the comment of [pLumo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/236063/plumo) and [How to use grep to get anything just after name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247812) a working command could be

```
 grep -oP "(?<=version: )(\d\.\d\.\d)" file.txt
```

Comment: Problem with lookbehind is that it has to be fixed number of characters, which does not work when with `\s+` or `\s*`. I usually prefer keep-out notation `\K` if possible.